# firebase-admin choose password reset link language, i.e. Spanish

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-admin

I have seen how to set the password reset language in the browser (`firebase/auth`) with `useDeviceLanguage()`, however I have not seen how to create the password reset link with `firebase-admin`

The code with `firebase-admin` to reset the password is below, but how can you change the language to, say, Spanish? The templates exist already in firebase.

```
const getPasswordResetLink = async email => {
  // HOW TO CHANGE LANGUAGE? 
  return admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(email)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** The link generates a `lang` property in the query string, you can manually change this after you get the link to say `lang=es`.

```
const getPasswordResetLink = async (email, languageSymbol) => {
  const link = await admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(email)
  const url = new URL(link)
  if (languageSymbol) {
    url.searchParams.set('lang', languageSymbol)
  }

  return url.toString()
}
```

As for the second argument in `generatePasswordResetLink()`, it doesn't appear there are any useful options to have this set from firebase, you need to do the solution above. Here is the second argument options for reference https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/bf4bacb18dc2e500a54ae7aa93b2db334c6ad4db/src/auth/index.ts#L947